# Исключить поля из конструктора lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

Как исключить поля из конструктора lombok? Или как создать конструктор не для всех полей в классе? В моём классе используется аннотация Builder, поэтому решение с аннотацией NonNull или ключевым словом final не подходят. Помню, что когда-то использовал какую-то аннотацию с параметром exclude, но сейчас не могу её найти.

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать `final`? Аннотация `@Builder` отлично дружит с ней и понимает, что такое поле нужно игнорировать.

Comment: @DmitriyD согласен, но тогда я гарантирую, что это поле не будет менять значение. А такое гарантировать не нужно.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/345520/